# how to save datagridview empty cell to database table

Tags: vb.net

Could somebody tell me how to update table with datagridview with blank cell in it? 
I have created a data entry form with datagridview with two columns in designer. I want to leave some cells of a column blank and save blank cells as zero in table. If there are no blank cells I can save datagridview content into table

```
Dim thisConnection As New SqlConnection()
Dim nonqueryCommand As SqlCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand()

Try
   ' Open Connection
   thisConnection.Open()
   Console.WriteLine("Connection Opened")

   ' Create INSERT statement with named parameters
   nonqueryCommand.CommandText = _
      "INSERT  INTO myTable (Col1, Col2) VALUES (@Col1, @Col2)"
  ' Add Parameters to Command Parameters collection
   nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@Col1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
   nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@Col2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)

   ' Prepare command for repeated execution
   nonqueryCommand.Prepare()

   ' Data to be inserted
   For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
     If Not row.IsNewRow Then
         nonqueryCommand.Parameters("@Col1").Value = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString
         nonqueryCommand.Parameters("@Col2").Value = row.Cells(1).Value.ToString
     End If
   Next

   nonqueryCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Catch ex As SqlException
   ' Display error
   Console.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.ToString())
Finally
   ' Close Connection
   thisConnection.Close()
   Console.WriteLine("Connection Closed")

End Try
```

I don’t know if this is correct way to check for empty cell in order to save into table. I get an error when I place the code between try and Catch ex As SqlException
An OleDbParameter with ParameterName '@Col1' is not contained by this OleDbParameterCollection

```
If row.Cells(0).Value.ToString IsNot Nothing Then
     nonqueryCommand.Parameters("@Col1").Value = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
else
     nonqueryCommand.Parameters("@Col1").Value = "0"
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

You do too much with your insert. All you need to do is to call `Parameters.AddWithValue` but the key here is to cast/convert your object values into DB-matching Data Type. Assuming, both values are `varchar` and nullable. See comments in code

```
nonqueryCommand.CommandText = _
  "INSERT INTO myTable (Col1, Col2) VALUES (@Col1, @Col2)"

' Prepare Parameters with correct Data Type

nonqueryCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col1", String.Empty)
nonqueryCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col2", String.Empty)

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    If Not row.IsNewRow Then
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters(0).Value = 
            If(row.Cells(0).Value Is Nothing, DbNull.Value, row.Cells(0).Value.ToString())
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters(1).Value = 
            If(row.Cells(1).Value Is Nothing, DbNull.Value, row.Cells(0).Value.ToString())

        ' Here Execute your query for each row
        If nonqueryCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0 Then 
            Debug.WriteLine("Inserted Values")
        End If
    End If
Next
```

That should be all you need. NOTE - the only time you need to set size of your parameters is when you have output parameters. On input, size sets automatically, when you add value. But remember to set size when retrieving *string* data from parameter.